# Separation of variables in Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am scratching my head to figure out a way to separate variables of the following equation:

$$(t+3)(t-2)dx = (t+tx^2)dt$$

Doesn't matter how many times I divide and multiply, I always get $x$ and $t$ on one side. Is there a trick applicable here?!

Comment: $(t+tx^2) = t(1+x^2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(t+3)(t-2) dx = (t+tx^2)dt \Rightarrow (t+3)(t-2)dx=t(1+x^2) dt \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{t}{(t+3)(t-2)} dt
$$
I assume you can take it from here.